# NPM command for run Node server after webpack finish building

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack, npm-scripts

I want to run a command like: npm run start:dev to make my node server runs but after webpack finished building bundles.

My current npm scripts are:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node server/server.js",
    "start:dev": "npm run build:prod & npm start",
    "lint": "eslint *",
    "build:dev": "webpack",
    "build:prod": "webpack -p --env production",
    "dev-server": "webpack-dev-server",
    "test": "cross-env NODE_ENV=test jest --config=jest.config.json"
},
```

The current command will kick both operations together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typo: you don't actually want to use `&`, you want `&&`:

```
"start:dev": "npm run build:prod && npm start",
```

A [single ampersand will background](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/86247/what-does-ampersand-mean-at-the-end-of-a-shell-script-line) the `run:build` job and cause `start` to run concurrently.

Comment: Thank you exactly what i want